# How to kill the sound of a browser using bashscript and not of any other music player?

Tags: bash

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

current_time_seconds = $(date +%s)
for VARIABLE in 1 2 3 4 5 .. 10
do 
        pid=`ps -ef | awk '/pulseaudio/{ print $2 }'`
        kill $pid
done
```

This is my bash script that just kills the pulse-audio process. Unfortunately, both my browser and musicplayer share the same process id. How do I kill the sound just for the browser, for lets say 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulseaudio treats each application as a separate client and gives each its own stream ("source"). You can use `pactl` to list clients, devices ("sinks") etc., and you can also use it to get/set their properties, such as their volume. There is even a convenient command to mute/unmute a source. Good luck!